# How to crop image so object is in center in Adobe PhotoShop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have taken some images of food on a plate, and I know the image is not dead in the center. How can I crop the image so that the plate is in the center?

Thanks

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but have you googled your question first? As Jenna says in her answer, there's a dedicated crop tool in Photoshop, which a simple google would give you tons of explanations for.

Comment: @Vincent I know how to use the crop tool, I was looking for a good way to crop an image with a specific object being in the exact center. A bit like if you want to draw a shape you can making your starting point the center.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to GD.SE!

You have some choices here.

You could insert some [guides or use a grid](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/grid-guides.html) to center the image in the file that you have open.

Or as you said you can crop your file.
To do this I would toggle the ruler (CTRL R) or else [place some guides in the exact location](http://www.photospinlabs.com/2010/10/place-guides-in-precise-locations-in-photoshop/) of where you would want to crop to.

I would then take the [crop tool](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/crop-image-cs6/) (C) and drag it out to those guides, hit enter to confirm and you are done.

Hope I've helped!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Find out the width of your canvas. (say 2400px)

Step 2. Put a guide in the middle of the canvas (in this case 1200 px)

Step 3. Measure the width of your image (Say 800 pixels)

Step 4. Put the middle of the image (400 pixels) on the guide.

Now step back (figuratively) and take a look at it. The image may be exactly in the center of your canvas but it may not look to be due to the composition of the image.  At this point you will have to decide whether to adjust the image or keep it in the mathematical center.

Good luck.

Comment: ...While accurate I think its important to mention Steps 1 and 3 are extraneous. Guides will snap to the middle by default.

Comment: @Ryan - you're correct. I was explaining the thought process.